# VNCviewer tunneling command failed

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, vncviewer

command:

```
vncviewer -via 192.168.x.x@administrator localhost:0

ssh: connect to host administrator port 22: No route to host
vncviewer: Tunneling command failed: /usr/bin/ssh -f -L 5599:localhost:5900 192.168.x.x@administrator sleep 20.
```

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user name and host are around the wrong way

> vncviewer -via 192.168.x.x@administrator localhost:0

Try

```
vncviewer -via administrator@192.168.x.x localhost:0
```

Also make sure you have you installed openssh-server?

```
apt-get install openssh-server
```